# Google app script to password protect excel / zip file

Tags: google-apps-script

I can create excel files and zip that file using Google App Script.  Both the Excel and Zip file can be password protected in their native applications, but I  cannot see a way to do this within Google App Script.

Is there any way to use Google App Script to add either a password to the excel file or a password to the zipped file?  Happy to use any of the common zip format if that helps

Comment: Not natively, no. You could write your own method of encryption, similar to [this template](http://support.smartcloud.ie/support/solutions/articles/3000053539-how-to-password-protect-a-google-sheet) which uses a Form and a deployed Web App to validate a stored password for the file.

Comment: Thanks Brian, but the example provided no longer works as the Protect File menu no longer appears.

Comment: You need to deploy the web app first as described in the article. Once you've done that, the Protect File option appears in the sheet.